# In superset, how do I exclude results where my field contains {} values?

Tags: presto, apache-superset

In superset I have a NullType field unappliedcodes that has some values that look like `{"BLAH":"Some info"}` and others look like `{}`

My goal is to exclude the {} entries and I have tried `WHERE NOT unappliedcodes = '{}'` and it does not work.

How do I exclude {} from my results?

Note: our data source is prestodb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the clause:
`WHERE NOT cardinality(unappliedcouponcodes) = 0`
per [prestodb docs](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/map.html?highlight=cardinality#map-functions)